# Need help to write a basic Command Line code

Tags: command-line, cmd

I'm using Windows 10 if it matters and I'm trying to feed a file to the "oeminst" app that will convert this file from .EDR to .CCSS. According to the app's website its usage summary is this:

```
oeminst [-options] [inputfiles]
 -v                      Verbose
 -n                      Don't install, show where files would be installed
 -c                      Don't install, save files to current directory
 -S d                    Specify the install scope u = user (def.), l = local system]
 infile                  Manufacturers setup.exe install file(s) or .dll(s) containing install files
 infile.[edr|ccss|ccmx]  EDR file(s) to translate and install or CCSS or CCMX files to install
                         If no file is provided, oeminst will look for the install CD.

more info can be found here https://www.argyllcms.com/doc/oeminst.html
```

So far I tried this code:

```
C:\Users\PC>oeminst infile. [C:\Users\PC\testfile.edr]
oeminst: Error - Unable to load file 'infile [C:\Users\PC\testfile]'
```

I'd appreciate if someone at least could tell me if I'm doing it right or not.

P.S. sorry for the messed up text. Not sure how to fix it. It looks good in editing mode.

Comment: I suspect your problem is that you are putting [brackets] around the file path and you shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

Try this : oeminst infile.edr C:\Users\PC\testfile.edr

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I got it.

C:\Users\PC>oeminst C:\Users\PC\testfile.edr